# Facebook Edit Events - Unknown Error returned

Tags: php, facebook

I'm hoping someone can help me.  I'm having problems getting the Facebook events_edit function working.  I can create events and cancel them no problem but when ever I try to edit them I get an "unknown error" message returned.

The code from the test console API is below (this is using the sample event information from the event_edit documentation but I have also tried my own event information).  I have tried canceling events with the same id as the ones I'm trying to edit and they cancel no problem so the id is definitely correct.

Any ideas?  Is their anyway I can get more information about an unknown error, as far as I can see everything is being passed through correctly.

Any help very much appreciated!!

Thanks
CK

Here is the code generated:
$facebook->api_client->events_edit(168516715889,'{"name":"name","category":"1","subcategory":"1",
"host":"host","location":"location","city":"Palo Alto","start_time":1215929160,"end_time":1215929160,"show_in_search":true}','');

The error message returned is error code 1, "An unknown error occurred".

Comment: Funny, I'm having the exact same issue right now.

Comment: Did you try removing the quotes around the category and subcategory values?

Comment: Yep tried that, still same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try creating and editing events using the new Graph API.  HTTP Post to `/me/events` with post parameters of name and start_time as well as other from the events subsection of http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/.  Once you have the ID, you can then modify the event by posting to `/{eventId}` with the parameter(s) you want to update.

Comment: Thanks DMCS, I hadn't looked at this for a long time, was for a proof of concept thing I was working on a couple of years ago. Hopefully this will help anyone who is having any issues with editing events now, although hopefully with the new Graph API there aren't any :)!